# Magento 2 PayPal Payment Standard For German Shop

Tags: magento2, paypal

I have a question about PayPal Payment Standard, it doesn't seems to be available for all countries. My shop is located in Germany, this country only has the option for express checkout. Can anyone tell me if it's allowed to use PayPal Standard for Germany since it's not available by default?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an answer here? I am facing the same question, in Magento 1 it was working perfectly with PayPal Payment Standard, but in Magento 2 its not available: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/paypal-countries.html
As PayPal Express is the only available payment method in Germany, this causes problems if you want to sell digital goods because according to the info statement on this page, PayPal Express does not support virtual or digital products: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/paypal-express-checkout.html

Comment: Yeah i've got it perfectly working with PayPal Express. You can try to put your country on default then the payment option should appear. Country regulations don't allow you to use the different versions of PayPal but you can just sign up with PayPal and use your credentials on the default. Hope this helps, if you have any further questions i'm happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

I talked to the PayPal Merchant support in Germany and they told me that Website Payment Standard is available in Germany and they have no idea why Magento2 does not offer it in Germany. In Magento 1, its possible to use Payment Standard by the way.

PayPal Express is not always a solution because this Payment Gateway does not support downloadable and virtual products.

Workaround: Switch the country to a country which allows PayPal Website Payment Standard (Austria for example), configure the Payment method and switch the country  back to Germany. The settings for Website Paymwent Standard in the Magento2 Backend will not show any more, but the payment method is working in the frontend.